# How do I get value as text (without executing formula) in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I searched the web trying to find how to solve this problem.
I set this macro in Google Sheet:

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('=IF(Dados!C10;"THIS IS " & Dados!C8; "THIS IS " & Dados!C8)');
```

But when the value of Dados!C8 is "01/20" I want to get the text: "THIS IS 01/20". Although, the result I get is "THIS IS 0.05". That's because It interprets as a formula, not as text.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

### You need to convert the date to a string with [text()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en), specifying the format

Sample:

```
=IF(Dados!C10,"THIS IS " & text(Dados!C8, "mm/dd"), "THIS IS " & text(Dados!C8, "mm/dd"))
```

Comment: Saved my life! Thank you!
How did you find the documentation for this at google? I couldn't find it :(

Comment: Glad to help! I googled for 'google sheets date to string' and found it :-)